# DPKG error when installing puppetserver

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, puppet

I want to install Puppet 4.2 on a Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty and when installing puppetserver through apt-get I get the following error near the end of the installation:

> dpkg: error processing archive
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/puppet-agent_1.2.2-1trusty_amd64.deb
>   (--unpack):
>   error setting ownership of
>   `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata.dpkg-new':
>   Operation not permitted

Afterwards when checking the service status it is listed as "puppetserver.dpkg-new" instead of simply puppetserver.

What's the problem? I run the apt-get with sudo.

Comment: Looks like a permission issue. What does `ls -laR /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/` show?

Comment: Please show the full command of what you're trying to do. "I run the apt-get with sudo" isn't very clear.

Comment: Is that directory on some remote/external/FUSE filesystem? What's the output of `df -T /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production`?